# SSIS - Insert value into variable using ADO.NET Connection

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, ssis, ado.net

I've got this error message while inserting value into variable using ADO.NET Connection

> [Execute SQL Task] Error: An error occurred while assigning a value to
>   variable "cekType": "The type of the value being assigned to variable
>   "User::cekType" differs from the current variable type. Variables may
>   not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except
>   for variables of type Object. ".

**My Setting in Execute SQL Task is:**

```
ResultSet: SingleRow;
SQLStatement: SELECT COUNT(1)  FROM table_A A LEFT JOIN table_B B ON A.ID=B.ID WHERE B.TYPE=A.TYPE AND B.DATEMOD=A.DATEMOD;
```

**Parameter Mapping:**

```
Variable Name: User::cekType;
Direction: Input;
Data Type: int32;
Parameter Name: @cekType
```

**Result Set**

```
Result name: 0;
Variable Name: User::cekType
```

Comment: if you are using sql-server why you have tag mysql  ?????

Comment: im using mysql for my db

Comment: Your left join returns regular inner join result. To get true left join behavoir, move the WHERE clause conditions to the ON clause.

Comment: What is the result you get when you execute the SQL Statement by itself?

Comment: @jarlh I've been trying the query in mysql server, and it works. but I have problem in inserting value from query result to variable in SSIS. thank you for answering :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Parameter Mapping. You only need the Result Set